# Vulkan instance

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, vulkan

I have been trying to launch avd on intelliJ, I keep on getting Vulkan instance error. I have installed Haxm, updated Android SDK, deleted avd and re-created it again, enabled VT-x in BIOS, tried with enabling Hyper-V and I switched graphics to software.

PC specs:

- Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @1.60GHz 1.60GHz, 4.00GB
- 4.00GB
- 64-bit Operating System
- Windows 10

This is is the error I keep on getting:

```
01:37   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:525: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
01:37   Emulator: WARNING: change of renderer detected.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the number of sites, your N3060 processor's integrated graphics chip  has no hardware support for the Vulkan API.

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/ru/ru/ark/products/91832/intel-celeron-processor-n3060-2m-cache-up-to-2-48-ghz.html

https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/celeron/n3060